# C++: Vector of struct in header file

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I've got a little question that drives me crazy but is probably a piece of cake for you guys. I defined a structure that consists of 4 numbers and I have a function which returns a vector of this structure. My header file looks like this:

Legendre.hpp

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>  //as suggested, but it doesn't help

#ifndef LEGENDRE_HPP_
#define LEGENDRE_HPP_    

struct FourDoubles {

    double Zeroth;
    double First;
    double Second;
    double Third;
};

std::vector<FourDoubles> LegendreLookupTable(int size);

#endif /* LEGENDRE_HPP_ */
```

(actually there are some more functions, so just ignore the seemingly pointless includes) 
Then I have the following cpp file that uses the header:

Legendre.cpp

```
#include "Legendre.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

vector<FourDoubles> LegendreLookupTable(int size) {

    vector<FourDoubles> res(size);
    int i;
    double x,x2,x3,x4;

    for(i=0;i<size;i++) {

    x=2.0*i/(size-1.0)-1.0;
    x2=x*x;
    x3=x2*x;
    x4=x3*x;
    res[i].Zeroth=x;
    res[i].First=1.5*x2-0.5;
    res[i].Second=2.5*x3-1.5*x;
    res[i].Third=4.375*x4-3.75*x2+0.375;
    }

return res;
}
```

Just in case anybody is curious: I'm calculating Legendre moments of an image. However, when I want to compile this, the compiler tells me "Field 'Zeroth' could not be resolved", same for the other fields.

The error occurs already when I comment out everything else in my files and when my main looks like

```
#include "Legendre.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
}
```

The error I get is as simple as
D

```
escription  Resource    Path    Location    Type
Field 'Third' could not be resolved Legendre.cpp    /Finder line 108    Semantic Error
Field 'Second' could not be resolved    Legendre.cpp    /Finder line 107    Semantic Error
Field 'Zeroth' could not be resolved    Legendre.cpp    /Finder line 105    Semantic Error
Field 'First' could not be resolved Legendre.cpp    /Finder line 106    Semantic Error
```

(don't mind the lines, as I said, I commented out a lot of stuff)

Two things are quite strange to me: If I don't declare a vector, but a FourDoubles directly like

```
vector<FourDoubles> LegendreLookupTable(int size) {

   ...
   FourDoubles test;
   test.Zeroth=5.5;
   ...
}
```

then it works perfectly fine. Also, when I write the whole stuff in my main file directly, e.g.

```
struct FourDoubles {

    double Zeroth;
    double First;
    double Second;
    double Third;
};

std::vector<FourDoubles> LegendreLookupTable(int size);

int main() {

   ...
}

vector<FourDoubles> LegendreLookupTable(int size) {
   ...
}
```

I'm probably missing something very basic here, but I just don't understand why it can't handle a vector of my struct unless it's declared in the main file. Any help to enlighten would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Did you include `vector`?

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. And copy-paste (as text) the full and complete (without modifications) error output, including possible informational notes.

Comment: Sorry about that, I will edit some clarification, give me a minute. However, as a matter of fact, I already posted a complete Example, because the error already occurs at compiling. I just commented out everything except the struct and function, even my main file is empty now. But I'll add the error output.

Answer (score 4):

You've forgotten to include the `<vector>` header in your hpp file. That's the real source of the error and that's why it works if you declare bare structure instead of vector of structures.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I just added "#include <vector>" to my hpp file and - I still get the same error. Also I didn't add that header to my main file before and as I said, if I have my struct and function declared in the main file, the whole vector thing works just as expected. (come to think of it, I wonder why it works when I didn't include the header)

Comment: That's interesting. I've copied your code and works in my case (Visual Studio 2015). Which openCV version are you using? Does it change anything if you throw out `using namespace std/cv` from your cpp file and use `std::vector` explicitly in function definition?

Comment: It's interesting that it's interesting, lol. I use openCV 3.2.0 but would that even be connected to openCV? I just removed the using namespace, still the same. I even killed every include except for <vector>. I can test it on another computer later, maybe there is something wrong with my system, especially since it works for you. (I use eclipse by the way)

Comment: If you used openCV < 3.0, there is a data structure called cv::vector and I was curious if that could be the problem since you've put using namespace std and cv in the same file. There is no cv::vector in your version though. Your IDE shouldn't matter - what may matter is your compiler, which is GCC judging by the error messages. I've written which IDE I'm using because VS means Microsoft VC++ compiler unless stated otherwise ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response. That nasty thing called real life kicked in and I was busy the last days. I checked my code on another computer and there are no errors. What I thought I knew about programming is right and there must be some weird bug somewhere in my dear Ubuntu (or maybe in gcc). So as far as I am concerned, that question can be closed.

Thanks a lot to KjMag. You helped me find out what's going on. Have a nice day.